# Assigning default value to .click function that loads when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there an easy way to make one of my divs load as the default one when the page loads?

Basically I want to show the reader always the first divs (d1) content when the page loads, with animation to keep it cohesive.

HTML / CSS

```
<style>
 .content {
 display: none;
 }
</style>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.1/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>

<ul>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d1" class="side">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d2" class="side">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d3" class="side">Link 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d4" class="side">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content" id="d1">
 Lorem ipsum 1.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d2">
 Lorem ipsum 2.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d3">
 Lorem ipsum 3.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d4">
 Lorem ipsum 4.
</div>
```

Javascript w/ JQuery 2.1.0

```
$('.side').click(function (ev) {
 "use strict";
 ev.preventDefault();
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 $(".side").not($(this).toggleClass("active")).removeClass("active");

 $.when($(".content").not($("#" + id)).velocity("transition.slideUpOut")).done(function () {
    $("#" + id).velocity("transition.slideDownIn");
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4hf7ygra/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call velocity method on first article id on document load event $("#d1").velocity("transition.slideDownIn");
```

```js
$(function(){

$("#d1").velocity("transition.slideDownIn");
    $('.side').click(function (ev) {
 "use strict";
 ev.preventDefault();
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 $(".side").not($(this).toggleClass("active")).removeClass("active");

 $.when($(".content").not($("#" + id)).velocity("transition.slideUpOut")).done(function () {
    $("#" + id).velocity("transition.slideDownIn");
 });
});
});
```

```css
 .content {
 display: none;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.1/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d1" class="side">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d2" class="side">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d3" class="side">Link 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-id="d4" class="side">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content" id="d1">
 Lorem ipsum 1.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d2">
 Lorem ipsum 2.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d3">
 Lorem ipsum 3.
</div>

<div class="content" id="d4">
 Lorem ipsum 4.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it on [`document.ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) this way:

```
$(function(){

$("#d1").velocity("transition.slideDownIn");

});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4hf7ygra/4/)